# airflow operator to download a file from URL and push to S3?

Tags: airflow

Is there an airflow operator to download a CSV file from a URL and upload the file into S3 ? I can upload a local-file to S3, but wanted to find out if there is an operator that will enable to upload the file into S3 without having to download the file into my local machine ?

Comment: no sir. there isn't such an operator. you'll have to cook up some code to download the file. For uploading you can leverage [`load_file()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/511d98e30ded2bcce9d246b358f806cea45ebcb7/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/s3.py#L430) method of `S3Hook`. I'm not aware of any way one could move remote file to S3 without downloading (unless of course, if you could directly trigger `aws s3 cp` command on that remote machine itself)

Comment: Ty. What I really meant to ask is this: Is there an operator that I can re-use ...obviously the csv-file needs to be downloaded to a machine and then uploaded to S3. I am just being lazy...so looking to find a readymade operator ...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution in my opinion is to use on_execute_callback for the most simple task (downloading the file in this case) and leaving the S3 operator the job to upload it.

Example (with GCS):

```
filename = "file-{{ts_nodash}}"
    
def run_and_download_file(context):
    resp = requests.get(".....")
    with open(filename) as f:
        f.write(resp.content)

upload_file = LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator(
    task_id="upload_file",
    src=filename,
    dst=filename,
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET,
    on_execute_callback=run_and_download_backup
)
```